# Big Query, Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a query encounterying this error message:
Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

I want to join tables representing behaviors happening in different time period, but normal join seems not working:

> select a.g, count(*) from
>
> (select user_id as user,
>
> (select x.value.string_value from
>   `analytics_156934592.events_20180701`, unnest(event_params) as x where
>   x.key = 'group') as g,
>
> (select x.value.string_value from
>   `analytics_156934592.events_20180701`, unnest(event_params) as x where
>   x.key = 'operation') as operation
>
> from `analytics_156934592.events_20180701` where event_name =
>   'book_now')a
>
> join
>
> (select user_id as user,
>
> (select x.value.string_value from
>   `analytics_156934592.events_20180702`, unnest(event_params) as x where
>   x.key = 'operation') as operation
>
> from `analytics_156934592.events_20180702` where event_name =
>   'book_now')b
>
> on a.user = b.user
>
> where a.operation = 'no_car' and b.operation = 'confirm'
>
> group by a.g

Not sure if it's a proper way to do joins with Big Query Standard Sql
Also the solutions to previous similar questions didn't work for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error message is clear, one or more of your subqueries in the select clause are generating more than one value.  There must be a better way to formulate your query than what you have now.

Comment: Simplify your query and figure out where the problem is.

Comment: You could use top 1 on your subqueries for solve the problem, but you need to check those sub queries in detail, because you could get wrong data

Comment: thanks all! I got the solution as below .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all!

I got a solution from my friend, and it is feasible:

```
select count(distinct a.user), count(distinct b.user_id)
from

(select
user_id as user

from `analytics_156934592.events_20180707`
join unnest(event_params) as x
join unnest(event_params) as y
where event_name = 'book_now'
and x.key = 'group'
and x.value.string_value = 'a'
and y.key = 'operation'
and y.value.string_value = 'no_car')a 

left join

(select
user_id , event_date

from `analytics_156934592.events_*` 
join unnest(event_params) as y
where event_name = 'launcher'
and y.key = 'operation'
and y.value.string_value = 'show'
AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'(\d+)') BETWEEN '20180708' and '20180720')b 

on a.user = b.user_id
```